# Missing Manifest.json file in Flutter Web Build

Tags: flutter

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter web project where the **manifest.json** file, referenced in the **index.html** file located in the web folder, is missing from the project directory. Despite the reference in index.html, the manifest.json file is not being generated during the build process. Consequently, when I run **flutter build web --release** to generate the production build, the manifest.json file is still absent in the build folder. This causes errors when I try to host the web app.

**Unable to find manifest.json**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.